# How to access individual tokens generated by push()?

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to make a simple blogging application in Android using Firebase. I am following the documentation which suggests that I use the push() method to circumvent overriding issues with features such as posting. I would like to create a function to remove a post from a blog (remove one of the unique keys generated from the push() method) but am unsure as to how to access the unique key to remove directly as it is randomly generated. Any suggestions/help?
Below is my Android code for reference.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    firebase = new Firebase("https://testingg.firebaseio.com/");
    posts = firebase.child("posts");
    Map<String, String> post1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    post1.put("author", "dankmaster");
    post1.put("title", "hiiiiiiiiiiii");
    posts.push().setValue(post1);   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android documentation for [Firebase.push()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#firebase_push) says that `.push()` returns a `Firebase` reference for the generated location.

So, set the `.push()` to a variable, and use `.getKey()` to get the ref's unique ID.

- Refer to the [Java Android Guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/).
- Specifically, [Saving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html) and [Retrieving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html) sections.